# Correct version of .lib of libpng

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, libpng

I am using Visual Studio 2013.
I have installed libpng through package manager console

```
Install-Package libpng
```

I would like to use function png_texture_load() from https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ahrs-visualizer/blob/master/png_texture.cpp

I copied .h and .cpp file to my project.

Tried to build, but I got a lot of errors LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

So I have tried to add libpng (libpng15.lib) here 
*Project Settings → Linker → Input → Additional Dependencies.*

But now I got

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file libpng15.lib
```

It seems it cannot find it. I have tried to add path (C:\Users\PanStudent\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\pa199_3DBreakout\packages\libpng.1.5.10.11) to
*Linker->General->Additional Library Directives*

Still the same. What can I do? Thanks

Edit: I have looked into the folder and there are many versions of libpng15.lib. Dynamic, static, debug, release, x64, win32. How can I find out which one is correct?

Comment: Well, if I dont I get a lot of errors LNK2019: unresolved external symbol, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `ItemDefinitionGroup` in `libpng.targets` file and you will see the condition `'$(PlatformToolset.ToLower())' == 'v100'` and `$(PlatformToolset.ToLower().IndexOf('v110'))`. But Visual Studio 2013 by default has `PlatformToolset v120`. So `libpng` just not compiled for VisualStudio 2013.

If `libpng` is C library, than you can just modify `*.target` files and add condition for `v120` toolset or you can just link library manually. In other cases you should rebuild libpng using VisualStudio 2013 compiler.

Static library in this context means static library with static C++ runtime (MT,MTd options for compiler). Dynamic library means dynamic library with dynamic C++ runtime (MD,MDd). When you use dynamic `libpng` you should copy dll files from `libpng.redist` to your application executable for start your program.